# windows wpf iteratively load Resource files

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources, iteration

I am working on a WPF application where I want to display a list of icons that I have embedded as png Images into the Resources folder of my project.
 The images' build action is 'resource', and they are located as follows:

```
'NameOfProject'/Resources/Icons/'SomeCategories'/'AllTheIcons'.png
```

Since there are about a thousand I would like to load them into the listview via a foreach-statement like so:

```
foreach (imageorwhatever icon in Resources/Icons/Category1) { ... }
foreach (imageorwhatever icon in Resources/Icons/Category2) { ... }
etc.
```

I haven't found a way so far on how I can achieve this. All solutions I have found target every resource individually, or load them from file.

I would prefer loading the images iteratively because I really don't want to define 1000 images in code or xaml

Answer (score 0):

To use them in WPF they need to be part of a ResourceDictionary so they are accessible. Here is some code that works for me:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ResourceTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow 
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var dict = new ResourceDictionary();

            var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("Images"))
            {
                dict.Add(file, new BitmapImage(new Uri(Path.Combine(baseDir, file))));
            }

            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("Images"))
            {
                var img = new Image();
                img.Source = (BitmapImage) FindResource(file);

                ListBox.Items.Add(img);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All you need is the ListBox in your XAML named "ListBox" to run this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="238" Margin="23,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
```

I didn't spend long on this and instead of that 2nd loop would be better just to drop the items into a List, then assign to the ResourceDictionary and then the ListBox, but this works.

EDIT: Forgot but the name of the resource I just make the filename as you can see in the above example. Might want to change that or at least remove the extension.